# Issue with persistent mongoDB data on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to store data in a mongoDB database on Amazon EC2. I'm using starcluster to configure and start the EC2 instance. I have an EBS volume mounted at /root/data. I installed mongoDB following the instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). When I log in to the EC2 instance I am able to type `mongo`, which brings me to the mongo shell with the `test` database. I have then added some data to a database, let's say `database1`, with various collections in it. When I exit the EC2 instance and terminate it, using `starcluster terminate mycluster`, and then create a new, different instance, the `database1` data is no longer shown in the mongo shell.

I have tried changing the dbpath in the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file to `/root/data/mongodb`, which is the EBS volume, and then start and stop the `mongodb` service using `sudo service mongodb stop` and `sudo service mongodb start`. I then try `mongo` again and receive

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
Sat Jan 19 21:27:42 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
exception: connect failed
```

An additional issue is that whenever I terminate the EC2 instance any changes I made to the config file disappear.

So my basic question is: how do I change where mongoDB stores its data on EC2 so that the data will remain when I terminate one EC2 instance and then start another EC2 instance.

#### Edit:

In response to the first answer:

1. The directory does exist
2. I changed the owner to `mongodb`
3. I then issued the command `sudo service mongodb stop`
4. Checked to see if the port is released using `netstat -anp | grep 27017`. There was no output.
5. Restarted mongodb using `sudo service mongodb start`
6. Checked for port 27017 again and receive no output.
7. Tried to connect to the mongo shell and received the same error message.
8. Changed the `mongodb.conf` back to the original settings, restarted mongodb as in the above steps, and tried to connect again. Same error.

The EBS volume is configured in the starcluster config to be reattached on each startup.

Answer (score 1):

For the "connect failed" after you change `/etc/mongodb.conf` problem, you can check the log file specified in the `/etc/mongodb.conf` (probably at `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`):

1. Check that the directory specified by `dbpath` exists.
2. Make sure it is writable by the "mongodb" user.  Perhaps it's best to chown to mongodb.
3. Make sure mongod actually released the 27017 port before starting it using: `netstat -anp | grep 27017`
4. Wait a couple seconds for `mongod` to restart before launching `mongo`.

It's not clear from your question if you are using [Starcluster EBS volumes for Persistent Storage](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/manual/volumes.html).  Note that [Ordinary EBS volumes](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/manual/configuration.html#amazon-ebs-volumes) do not automatically persist and reattach when you terminate an instance and start another.  You would need to attach and mount them manually.

Once you get that working you'll probably want to create a [custom Starcluster AMI](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/manual/create_new_ami.html) with mongo properly installed and /etc/mongodb.conf appropriately modified.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect your answers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there anything informative in the mongodb.log after each step?

Comment: The only thing I've noticed is: `Mon Jan 21 17:28:30 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::exists: Permission denied: "/root/data/mongodb", terminating`. I don't know why this is. Here's the output of `ls -l`: `drwxrwxrwx 3 mongodb root 4096 2013-01-20 17:15 mongodb`, so I don't know why this is occuring.

Comment: Something strange going on with your permissions. Have you tried working through the ec2 tutorials? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2+Quickstart